# livepatch fails with error "cannot apply patches: cannot apply update: cannot execute finitModule syscall: required key not available"

Tags: 18.04, canonical-livepatch

I have canonical-livepatch running but it shows the error messages below. First it tried to update with the error `cannot apply patches: cannot apply update: cannot execute finitModule syscall: required key not available`. After that failure, it refuses to try another update again.

What could be the problem in applying the update? I couldn't find anything about that error message.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

```
$ journalctl -t canonical-livepatch
[...]
Jun 17 23:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: Client.Check
Jun 17 23:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: Checking with livepatch service.
Jun 17 23:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: updating last-check
Jun 17 23:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: touched last check
Jun 17 23:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: Applying update 52.3 for 4.15.0-51.55-generic
Jun 17 23:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: cannot apply update: cannot execute finitModule syscall: required key not available
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: Client.Check
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: Checking with livepatch service.
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: updating last-check
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: touched last check
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: No updates available at this time.
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: Module may have caused kernel crash! Not inserting module.
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_4_15_0_51_55_generic_52_52.3
Jun 18 00:11:24 callisto canonical-livepatch[1183]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: lock file "/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_4_15_0_51_55_generic_52_52.3" already exists
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have Secure Boot enabled and did not import the Livepatch key: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+bug/1833566

You can [apparently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch) fix this by running:

```
sudo mokutil --import /snap/canonical-livepatch/current/keys/livepatch-kmod.x509
```

(the password you enter will only be used once)

Then, reboot and follow the instructions to import the key.

Comment: That sounds like it might be the problem; secure boot is enabled. Unfortunately, for the key enrollment I'd need physical access and the machine is headless so I can't easily try it right now.