# LivePatch fails with error "cannot apply patches: lock file already exists"

Tags: 20.04, canonical-livepatch

The canonical live-patch icon in my rack started showing a red "!" symbol and on opening the window, I get the error message "Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues for further information.".

I digged around a bit and here are the logs I get after running the following commands:

journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch

```
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: Client.Check
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: Module may have caused kernel crash! Not inserting module.
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_39_43_generic_69_69.1
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: during refresh: multiple failures
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: during refresh: cannot check: apply-failed
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: during refresh: cannot apply patches: lock file "/var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_39_43_generic_69_69.1" already exists
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: failure when getting status: apply-failed
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: failure getting status after refresh: apply-failed
```

sudo canonical-livepatch refresh

```
checking for patches
nothing to apply
kernel: 5.4.0-39.43-generic
patch state: ✗ the application caused a crash last time it was applied, check system logs with `journalctl -f -t canonical-livepatch`
patch version: 69.1
```

I had tried going in and deleting the mentioned file in /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks, but even on rebooting, the same error still appears.

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: I think this links is solution for above issue: [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160504/1121286)

Answer (score 2):

```
Jul 25 23:23:08 castaire-thonkpad canonical-livepatch[1023]: To override this warning, remove /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/common/locks/livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_39_43_generic_69_69.1
```

After remove the `livepatch_Ubuntu_5_4_0_39_43_generic_69_69.1` repeat `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh`, it worked for me.

Comment: Removing recent lock file, solved my problem.

Comment: Had the same issue after clearing the SecureBoot password. Problem remained after performing MOK management as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues , but after removing the lock file the refresh worked again.